# Not contain a(n) armv7s slice Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

In My PhoneGap Application The Application is working fine in developer Mode. But I Make Archive it give following Error.

```
ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/Shared/PhoneGap/Frameworks/PhoneGap.framework/PhoneGap for architecture armv7s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Please Help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Build Settings and Compare your settings to following screenshot. I Hope it will help for you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try This and Hope will help you

- Remove the support for any architecture `armv7s` from the `project (target)`  -> `Build Settings` -> `Valid Architectures`:

Alternatively, you can set the flag for your debug configuration's

- Change `Build Active Architecure Only` to `Yes` !